# Syntax formatting is a mess

Tags: bug, documentation

I just got started with Docs and I'm already having problems with the Syntax section.

In this section, everything is supposed to be a code block. For some reason, it allows all types of formatting. Including `` `code` `` (which just changes the font).

For example, I added a table with the table button. It didn't completely fail, but it looks bad because there needs to be more space between columns. I tried to circle where, but there was no room:

> [image: FlavorMatch]

---

Clicking the blue circle lead to **general** editing help. It's not the [normal page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), but instead [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting), which isn't even entirely specific to Documentation.

---

According to the sidebar and the empty input box (which I guess I ignored the first time around), we're supposed to use `- list items`. This too is a little ambiguous, since I tried using a numbered list and it didn't really work:

> [image: no numbers for my list here]

---

Also, where's the syntax highlighting?

Comment: Tables don't belong in the Syntax section. It looks weird because all the table styles are being ignored because it's being placed into a code block. The real solution is to give an error message when trying to do that, like it does for other block content which can't be placed there.

Comment: @animuson I guess I'm really confused about the Syntax section. Why does it let me add markdown? It **does** try to format everything, including links, code (which changes font), and, of course, tables. If this is intended behavior, then the bug is the confusing UI.

Comment: The syntax section is supposed to be a list of one-liners that represent how to use it. You don't put it in a table, you would just do `- preg_match(yada yada)` as a line, and `- re.search(yada yada)` as another line. It then formats those list items automatically into neat code blocks.

Comment: That intention breaks down in cases where there is no good one-liner representation of a syntax, @Animuson. For example, any decent syntax for a try-finally block will use multiple lines in nearly any language. I think it would be better for the Syntax section to use the same formatting rules as all the others, and for the list layout to be something applied by convention rather than enforced by the tool.

Comment: For me, the formatting behavior of the comment section caused an issue with a proposed change by concatenating two spaces into one (see [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347965/why-was-this-proposed-documentation-change-rejected))