# Adjacent whitespace in Syntax items should not be compressed

Tags: bug, documentation, code-formatting, markdown-rendering

I was editing a Documentation Topic's Syntax section, putting a very brief description in a code comment after each element, and I noticed that three of the spaces in my source had up and gone:

---

Editor:
[image: Properly-spaced comment after code]

---

Rendered preview:
[image: Markdown-mangled-spaced comment after code]

---

Even though these lines are short, this is code:

**Please preserve whitespace in this section.**

Comment: Yes, I know I can use `&nbsp;`, but I shouldn't have to.

Comment: "1 spaces." ***TRIGGERED***

Comment: Yeah, sorry, BoltClock: it's not sentence; I shouldn't have added that period. ;D

Comment: Probably related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329466/syntax-formatting-is-a-mess