# Why was this proposed documentation change rejected?

Tags: support, documentation, suggested-edits

I've recently proposed a [change](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/136499?filter-tags=python) for the Python Documentation. In this edit, I've changed the syntax section of the "Comments and Documentation" topic to make the comments described there valid according to [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#inline-comments) (specifically, there were not enough spaces before and after the `#` signs).

The edit was rejected for *"not attempt[ing] to explain or illustrate the 
topic"*. This surprised me.

I still assume my edit was correct on the content level, as I've just changed the comments to make them valid according to the official specification.
I could however imagine that my change wasn't clearly visible to the reviewers as a different number of spaces is easy to be overseen, but I'm not sure with this.

I didn't want to resubmit the edit directly with an improved description, so I'm asking here on Meta: Can I resubmit this edit if I point out the changes (the inserted spaces) more exactly in the description? Or is something else wrong with it?

**Update:** I've noticed that the two spaces before the inline comment which I added were concatenated into one space in the rendered view. Of course, I could now imagine this as good and reasonable rejection reason. I've fixed this in the draft of the change I will submit if the community won't point out other errors.

Comment: I'd say resubmit the edit (preferably citing PEP 8).

Comment: @ayhan I've [resubmitted the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/136675) now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the question update, I found out that my edit had (most likely) two major issues:

1. It was not clearly visible that I've inserted some spaces
2. The editor concatenated two following spaces, making the edit incorrect

I've fixed both issues by giving a clear descrption and replacing the two spaces with `&nbsp;&nbsp;` and [resubmitted the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/136675). It was accepted fast.

At least for the source of the second issue, there are already questions on Meta about it: [This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/330026/adjacent-whitespace-in-syntax-items-should-not-be-compressed) describes specifically my problem, [this (more general) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329466/syntax-formatting-is-a-mess) asks why all input is formatted as Markdown although everything is expected to be code.